# GLSL 4.2 Image load and store & memoryBarrier

Tags: opengl, concurrency, thread-safety, glsl, textures

Using image load and store, i would like to do the following in GLSL 4.2:

```
vec3 someColor = ...;
vec4 currentPixel = imageLoad(myImage, uv);
float a = currentPixel.a/(currentPixel.a+1.0f);
vec4 newPixel = vec4(currentPixel.rgb*a+someColor*(1.0f-a),currentPixel.a+1.0f);
imageStore(myImage, uv, newPixel);
```

the value for 'uv' can be the same for multiple rasterized pixels. In order to get the proper result, of course I want no other shaderexecution to write into my pixel inbetween the calls of imageLoad() and imageStore();

Is this possible to do somehow with memoryBarrier? if so, how does it have to be used in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the value for 'uv' can be the same for multiple rasterized pixels.

Then you can't do it.

`memoryBarrier` is not a way to create an atomic operation. It *only* guarantees the ordering for a single shader's operation. So if a particular shader invocation reads an image, writes it, and then reads it again, you need a `memoryBarrier` to ensure that what is read is what was written before. If some *other* shader invocation wrote to it, then you're out of luck (unless it was a dependent invocation. The rules for this stuff are complex).

If you're trying to do programmatic blending, then you need to make certain that each fragment shader invocation reads/writes to a *unique* value. Otherwise, it's not going to work.

You don't say what it is you're trying to actually achieve, so it's not possible to provide a better way of getting what you want. All I can say is that *this* way is not going to work.

Comment: okay - already thoght so. thanks a lot for clarification. yes I try to do blending. I could use ImageAtomicAdd(.., vec4(someColor,1.0f)) and when reading the pixels dividing by their .a value - but the problem is that the pixels initially already have a color as well as a weight, and this weight is somewhere between 0 and 1

Comment: @user1282931: If you're trying to do blending, why do you have multiple fragments writing to the same value?

Comment: it's kind of a backprojection onto a reflection map. the rendered reflection is present as well as the objectnormals perpixel and from this a reflectionmap should be aproximated - so multiple fragments may map to the same reflection texel and in order to avoid noise i want to use blending

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement locking system (lock / mutex). 
For this purpose, it is good to use imageAtomicCompSwap or if buffer is used, atomicCompSwap. Ofcourse you would need to use global variable (say texture) not local one.

For implementation purpose, I think this question is in big part answer to your problem: [Is my spin lock implementation correct and optimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383363/is-my-spin-lock-implementation-correct-and-optimal)