# would this be a functioning spinlock in c?

Tags: c, operating-system, mutex, atomic, spinlock

I am currently learning about operating systems and was wondering, using these definitions, would this be working as expected or am I missing some atomic operations?

```c
int locked = 0;

void lsLock(){
  while(1) {
    if (locked){
      continue;
    } else {
      locked = 1;
      break;
    }
  } 
}

void lsUnlock(){
  locked = 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. Spinlock implementation requires locking instructions which are not standard. You need to use compiler-specific code to implement it. You can start by looking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383363/is-my-spin-lock-implementation-correct-and-optimal

Comment: Imagine two threads running the `lsLock` function, both of them start execution with `locked == 0` - both of them check `if (locked)` - both of them see that it's zero - both of them lock it.

Comment: @4386427 I forgot the break in the else block. But even with it, it won't work, right?

Comment: @Flowmotion No, it won't work. For several reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that the compiler assumes that nothing will be altered by anything "external" (unless it's marked `volatile`); which means that the compiler is able to optimize this:

```
int locked = 0;

void lsLock(){
  while(1) {
    if (locked){
      continue;
    } else {
      locked = 1;
      break;
    }
  } 
}
```

..into this:

```
int locked = 0;

void lsLock(){
  if (locked){
    while(1) { }
  }
  locked = 1;
}
```

Obviously that won't work if something else modifies `locked` - once the `while(1) {}` starts it won't stop. To fix that, you could use `volatile int locked = 0;`.

This only prevents the compiler from assuming `locked` didn't change. Nothing prevents a theoretical CPU from playing similar tricks (e.g. even if `volatile` is used, a non-cache coherent CPU could not realize a different CPU altered `locked`). For a guarantee you need to use atomics or something else (e.g. memory barriers).

However; with `volatile int locked` it may work, especially for common 80x86 CPUs. Please note that "works" can be considered the worst possibility - it leads to assuming that the code is fine and then having a spectacular (and nearly impossible to debug due to timing issues) disaster when you compile the same code for a different CPU.